# SortedList and Linq

Tags: c#, sortedlist

I'm confused after reading the documentation on what to expect when using Linq with a SortedList.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319(v=vs.110).aspx

I guess the enumeration is guaranteed to be sorted and also retrieve by index, but what about Values and Keys? Are all these cases safe?

```
        var list = new SortedList<DateTime, object>();

        //add entries here ...

        var firstValue1 = list.Values[0];
        var firstValue2 = list.First().Value;
        var firstValue3 = list.Values.First();

        var firstKey1 = list.Keys[list.Count-1];
        var firstKey2 = list.First().Key;
        var firstKey3 = list.Keys.First();

        var sortedList = list.Where(x => x.Key > DateTime.Now)
            .Select(x => x.Value);
```

Comment: The point of Linq queries is to actually query something so just going `.First().Value` is as good as random to me.

Comment: @EpicKip: I don't follow. What makes that random rather than getting the first item in a sorted list?

Comment: `The elements of a SortedList object are sorted by the keys either according to a specific IComparer implementation specified when the SortedList is created or according to the IComparable implementation provided by the keys themselves.`

Comment: `The index sequence is based on the sort sequence. When an element is added, it is inserted into SortedList in the correct sort order, and the indexing adjusts accordingly. When an element is removed, the indexing also adjusts accordingly. `

Comment: @Chris reading `.First()` is never telling you what you're getting. I'd rather always say what I'm looking for and only use `.First()` if I just need an item to test with or something

Comment: @EpicKip it tells you exactly what you're getting. The first item in the enumeration. There are many scenarios when that's exactly what you need.

Comment: @EpicKip: If you know nothing of the underlying item then you might be right but in this case its a sorted list. You are getting a very specific thing. The earliest item, the latest item, the item with the highest score... Whatever your sorting is defines what the first item is. Would you also consider it pointless to write `.OrderBy(x=>x.Thing).First()`?

Comment: @Daveoc64 You could need it from time to time, but that doesn't mean you should always use a sortedlist and .First. More often in production people tend to just sort manually so they know what they are getting

Comment: @Chris No then I actually know from reading it what I'm sorting on. By reading the linq query

Comment: @EpicKip If you don't like using `SortedList`, then say *that*.  Saying that using `First` is getting you a "random" element, when it's objectively *not* doing that, is just flat wrong.  Saying you don't like the design of `SortedList` (and ordered collections in general, by the sounds of it) and what it does to your code is a matter of opinion that you're more than welcome to hold.

Comment: @EpicKip: You should know exactly what your sorted list is sorting on too... The framework doesn't just pick a random item to sort your list by, you tell it exactly what you want... I suspect that you know this though and this is just going to have to be put down to a difference of opinion.

Comment: @Chris I worded my first comment wrong, not what I meant to say (fully). I mean if I read `someList.OrderyBy(x => x.Something).First()` I can tell on that line what its sorting on, if I see `someList.First()` I cant

Comment: @EpicKip: Ah, that makes more sense. I still don't necessarily agree with you but I much more see your point of view. ;-)

Comment: @Chris That's ok of course, I figured I was being a bit too hasty with my comments and may not have said what I want to say thanks for dealing with a hothead like me and stay 100% civil ;)

Comment: It was a close run thing. There were a few edits to make my responses a little more civil before posting. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation...

From the [documentation on the Values property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132380(v=vs.110).aspx):

> "The order of the values in the `IList<T>` is the same as the order in the `SortedList<TKey, TValue>`."

From the [documentation on the Keys property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132379(v=vs.110).aspx):

> "The order of the keys in the `IList<T>` is the same as the order in the `SortedList<TKey, TValue>`."

Comment: Thanks, my doubt is gone. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the source code here:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/sortedlist.cs,de670561692e4a20

Apparently, the `Keys` property is just a wrapper around an instance of this class:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/sortedlist.cs,374aa21b960ae2e2

If you look at the `GetEnumerator()` method, you can see it creates a `SortedListKeyEnumerator`. Here's the source code for that:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/sortedlist.cs,a4492235f85c77d8

As far as I can tell, the `MoveNext()` of this just iterates through the keys of the contained `SortedList`.

You can find out the same way how `Values` works.

Comment: Source code can change, documented guarantees will not. :)

Comment: @Stig Documentation guarantees also change, just less often.  C#, and .NET have indeed made breaking changes before, albeit sparingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code of Enumerable.cs, you will see that the overload without a predicate simply tries to treat the source as an IList and if that doesn't work, it returns the first element using the enumerator. Both the index and the enumerator are supposed to be handled internally by the SortedList class so that you get the appropriate (sorted) result:

```
public static TSource First<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
            if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
            IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
            if (list != null) {
                if (list.Count > 0) return list[0];
            }
            else {
                using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
                    if (e.MoveNext()) return e.Current;
                }
            }
            throw Error.NoElements();
        }
```

The overload with a predicate works slightly different in that it executes the predicate against every item using the enumerator, looking for the first match:

```
    public static TSource First<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
        foreach (TSource element in source) {
            if (predicate(element)) return element;
        }
        throw Error.NoMatch();
    }
```

Either way, you should be getting the same (sorted) result.